# Unable publish Google App Script to the G Suite Marketplace for domain administrators to find

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, publish, google-apps-marketplace

My Google App Script (an add-on for Google Docs) has passed the OAuth verification and has also been verified by the Google team.  The application is both "Published"  and "GAM: Published", yet Domain Admins are unable to locate the add-on when searching for it, and therefore cannot install it to their domain users.

I have read the following two articles many times:

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-addons
https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-for-domains

I've been liaising with the docs-addon-advisor, who has approved the add-on again and again, but nothing seems to impact the Marketplace Apps search results.  It is however availble in the Web Store search results.  They have directed me back to this forum for advice.

I've followed the articles above and see no error messages in the publication, yet still the add-on remains invisible to the Domain Admin world.

You can see that DocuSign is happily installed in my domain, I can search for it, and it has been pushed down onto my domain users.  So what I'm trying to achieve is possible.  My add-on is simply absent from this marketplace search for some reason.

Any ideas?

[image: admin console for my domain account]

[image: My app script alongside DocuSign]

[image: developer dashboard]

[image: GSuite Marketplace SDK configured]

[image: domain admins cannot locate app]

[image: developer consoles shows published]

[image: Visibilitye]

Answer (score 2):

Your add-on is published at https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/seal_atn/820114923602. It does not have "Enable individual install" checked so it's installable and searchable only by domain admins.

Comment: It's finally searchable.  The last thing I did was to un-check the "Enable individual install" option.  Didn't realise that this impacted the marketplace search.  Thanks for the explanation